# Why does script in if-up.d not mount my samba share?

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, samba

I have an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount a windows share

```
//192.168.178.4/files   /media/share/d   cifs   credentials=/home/arnold/.credentials,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777   0 0
```

that is not mounted during boot/login. When I login I see that the share is not mounted, after a `sudo mount -a` it is. In the [mint forums it was suggested](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=236712&view=unread&sid=8e629f7430248667be5e9f0f604ace95#unread) that the network was not up and running. Creating a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/fstab` (or another name) would solve the problem. In fact, this directory is intended for scripts like this. An excellent suggestion. I created the script but alas it did not work. I added some logging statements and the script reads like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME fstab before mounting" >>/var/log/fstab.log
#mount -av >>/var/log/fstab.log
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME fstab mount executed" >>/var/log/fstab.log
echo " " >>/var/log/fstab.log
```

The script is executable and the owner is root. When I execute the script after login the share is properly mounted. I made sure the logfile was empty and copied it directly after login where it reads:

```
01/03/2017 09:55:45  before mounting
/                        : ignored
/data                    : already mounted
/home                    : already mounted
none                     : ignored
01/03/2017 09:55:45  mount executed

01/03/2017 09:55:45  before mounting
/                        : ignored
/data                    : already mounted
/home                    : already mounted
none                     : ignored
01/03/2017 09:55:45  mount executed

01/03/2017 09:55:51  before mounting
/                        : ignored
/data                    : already mounted
/home                    : already mounted
none                     : ignored
01/03/2017 09:55:51  mount executed
```

It executes three times (once for each network interface?). When next I run `sudo mount -av` I get:

```
/                        : ignored
/data                    : already mounted
/home                    : already mounted
none                     : ignored
/media/share/d           : successfully mounted
```

As you can see by comparing these two logs no (visible) attempt is made by mount to mount the network share during boot.

I did get many excellent suggestion for workarounds in the Linux forums, but none answered the question why the script in the `if-up.d` does behave that weird and I have no solution that gives me a mounted share from the terminal (it is accessible via the file browser though). I have the following questions:

- is `if-up.d` the place for mounting a file share?
- if so, what could be the reason that it does not work on my system (what am I doing wrong?)
- if not, what is the regular place to go for these mounts?

I am a Linux newbie and I see this problem as a crash course in Linux :-), but bear with me if I do not understand a suggestion at once.

Using mint 18.1 with mate, server is a QNAP NAS that has the most recent firmware.

**Edit** I was looking for spots in logs that mentioned something about mounting this share, and I found some entries in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Wait Online.
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: Mounting /media/share/d...
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus mount[1301]: error 2 (No such file or directory) opening credential file /home/arnold/.credentials
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: media-share-d.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=2
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/share/d.
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: remote-fs.target: Job remote-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan  3 09:19:53 lassus systemd[1]: media-share-d.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

The credentials file absolutely exists. I changed owner from myself to root, but that didn't help either.

Comment: It seems that `mount` tries to access the credentials file before `/home` is mounted...

Comment: Ah, the network might be up, but /home not. Do you think that root would be mounted before anything else?

Comment: And it is! Moving the credentials file to /etc did it. Thank you! If you make this an answer I'll vote it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm collecting the comments as an answer in case someone face the same situation or has a better knowledge to improve the information.

The behaviour you noticed seems to be a consequence of the fact that, while trying to mount your samba share, `mount` is unable to access the credentials file.

But the credentials file exists, and it is readable by `mount`, so the problem seems to be the `/home` partition not available (not mounted) when needed.

Moving the credentials file somewhere inside the `/` partion (inside `/etc` for example) solves the problem.

Comment: I might add that in doing so *all* fstab entries are mounted and that a separate script in `if-up.d` is no longer needed. What might have aggravated the problem is that my `/home` directory is encrypted so that it takes longer to mount.

Answer (score 0):

Use crontab as root:

```
@reboot until /usr/bin/fping -q 192.168.178.4; do sleep 1;done && /bin/mount -av
```

Comment: It does not work. Does crontab execute with superuser permission?